# Why does linear combination of dirichlet function is not a step function？

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> > [image]

I know that Dirichlet function is not Riemann integrable but only Lebesgue integrable which has measure zero. I am having issue to understand the example that a simple function which is not step function. I know linear combination of Dirichelt function is simple function, but Why doessuch function is not a step function? It seems to fit the definiton of step function.

Comment: Because the rational numbers are not an interval.

Comment: @ Severin Schraven Yeah, but $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ indeed defined on the interval, it only said taking 1 at rational and 0 at irrational, isn't it? So what does step function actually considering?

Comment: A step function is 0 on some interval and 1 on other intervals. In particular there are only finitely many jumps. Which is a huge difference to the Dirichlet function.

Answer (score 2):

If the Dirichlet function was a step function then you could find an open interval $I = (a,b)$ on which the Dirichlet function is constant ($0$ or $1$). This is not possible since each open interval contains both rational and irrational numbers.